# ASP.NET MVC DataColumn: Combine two cells to represent a column

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, datacolumn

I'm exporting a gridview into an excel sheet in my ASP application.
Also I'm able to add columns through

```
var reportView = new System.Data.DataTable();
reportView.Columns.Add("Subject");
```

and rows through:

```
reportView.Rows.Add("English");
```

Now here I'm stuck. I want to combine two cells for column title and write text "Subject" into it. And for the values will be adding two different values as displayed in following figure:

```
   Subject
Value 1| Value 2
Value 1| Value 2
Value 1| Value 2
Value 1| Value 2
```

Any help please!

Comment: you can add append multiple values using Stringbuilder and then use it on `reportView.Rows.Add`

Comment: But that won't show two values in two different columns right ???

Comment: When you append the values, that means you are forming a single string from two different strings. Then use the appended value.First add the column to your list of columns. Then - 
    `string combinedVal = col1.value + col2.value`
    `reportView.Rows.Add(combinedVal)`

Comment: That will show the combined value in a single column, agreed. But what I want is that there should be two columns but the header of the column should be one(merged)

Comment: In that case, you will have to make modifications to your excel object after your data is loaded into excel object. What are you using for exporting to excel?

Comment: any idea regarding this ?

Comment: post your code about how you are exporting to excel. particularly interested in the library being used.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155174/discussion-between-piyush-khanna-and-syed-asad-abbas-zaidi).